How to message using zmq with remote machines
I was planning to use zmq to communicate between a personal laptop and a remote machine. I plan to use the laptop as the server and the remote machine as a client. Currently, I use a vpn to get into the remote machine's network and use ssh to access the machine.
I was trying to use some of the tutorial code on the zmq documentation to see if the messages sent are received and that doesn't work.
Server code:
#
#   Hello World server in Python
#   Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
#   Expects b"Hello" from client, replies with b"World"
#

import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)

    #  Do some 'work'
    time.sleep(1)

    #  Send reply back to client
    socket.send(b"World")

Client code:
#
#   Hello World client in Python
#   Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
#   Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back
#

import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print("Connecting to hello world server…")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://ip_addr_of_laptop:5555")

#  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
for request in range(10):
    print("Sending request %s …" % request)
    socket.send(b"Hello")

    #  Get the reply.
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received reply %s [ %s ]" % (request, message))

I tried looking into ssh tunneling and I was confused as how to set it up for my use case.

What you wish is called
remote forwarding.
(The VPN doesn't appear to be helping you here;
perhaps it chooses to firewall/block inbound connect requests.
And thank you for the reproducible example.)
Connect from laptop to the remote machine.
Test whether you can get service on port 5555 --
we expect the answer is "no".
(If you see IPv6 address ::1 mentioned, just ignore it.)
lap$ ssh the_remote_machine

rem$ telnet localhost 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Now re-connect with forwarding enabled.
rem$ exit

lap$ ssh -R 5555:localhost:5555 the_remote_machine

rem$ telnet localhost 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Excellent!
Now your python client code can connect to tcp://localhost:5555,
and the remote's sshd will send the data back to the laptop's ssh,
which will connect to laptop zmq server on your behalf.

Imagine that an unrelated zmq daemon was already running on the remote server,
so you need to pick a different port.
You could do it like this.
lap$ ssh -R 5556:localhost:5555 the_remote_machine

rem$ telnet localhost 5556
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.

The zmq server back on the laptop knows nothing of these shenanigans,
and happily sticks to the usual port 5555.
